# Is the C language supported as a V-REP script

Tags: simulation, robotics

I am quite new to V-rep and while I'm reading the documentation, in the section Regular API, all the provided script functions are written for both Lua and C, but officially, Lua is the supported language for scripting.

My question is, can I write the scripts in C ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the only thing you can do is to use the remote API to write an external C++ program that handles the simulation.